# What does stage mean in the spark logs?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

When I run a job using spark I get the following logs?

`[Stage 0:>                (0 + 32) / 32]`

Here 32 corresponds to the number of partitions of rdd that I have asked for.

However I am not getting why are there multiple stages and what exactly happens in each stage.

Each stage apparently takes a lot of time. Is it possible to get done in fewer stages?

Comment: Take a look at this presentation which explained it quite well https://spark-summit.org/2014/talk/a-deeper-understanding-of-spark-internals

Answer (score 8):

A stage in Spark represents a segment of the DAG computation that is completed locally. A stage breaks on an operation that requires a shuffling of data, which is why you'll see it named by that operation in the Spark UI. If you're using Spark 1.4+, then you can even visualize this in the UI in the DAG visualization section:

[image]

Notice that the split occurs at `reduceByKey`, which requires a shuffle to complete the full execution.